# Can one have two random variables, perfectly correlated, but with different variances (as percent of their mean)?

Tags: correlation, variance

I'm thinking of the difference between two random variables, e.g. the spread between two stock prices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure you can, e.g.

```
set.seed(38821010)

x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 5*x + 3

var(y)/mean(y)
var(x)/mean(x)

cor(x,y)
```

as an example.

Answer (score 2):

I think to put what Peter said in simple terms.  If Y is a linear function of X the absolute value of the Pearson correlation is 1. But the variances will differ unless the coefficient of X is 1.  This is simply due to the fact that

Var(cX)=c$^2$Var(X) and Var(X+a)=Var(X) for any constants a and c.

Now adding the idea that they are different with regard to the ratio to the mean we see that

E(cX+a)=cE(X) +a.  So Var(Y)/E(Y)=c$^2$ Var(X)/(cE(X)+a) Take a=0 and c>0 and c not equal to 1 then

Var(Y)/E(Y)=c Var(X)/E(X) which is not equal to Var(X)/E(X).